# Perl equivalent of a sample JavaScript codes

Tags: javascript, perl, http-request

I have this code:

```
  request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData
  })
```

I'd like to convert that into Perl, what I have so far is:

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages');
$req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
$req->content( $messageData );
```

I not sure how I can incorporate the following line into my Perl code:

```
qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
```

It specifies a query parameter to add to the URL.

I tried to search the net but most example either sends the json content or the query string but not both.  I need something that can send both if my interpretation to the JavaScript code is correct.

Thanks in advance to anyone who will guide me.

Comment: not sure if it is a custom http header, I assumed it meant 'query string', I guess I should have tried declaring it as a custom header.  Trying it now.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI) module (possibly supplemented by the [URI::QueryParam](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI::QueryParam) module) to build (and manipulate) a URL.

```
use HTTP::Request::Common qw( POST );
use JSON::XS              qw( encode_json );
use URI                   qw( );

my $message_data = encode_json(...);

my $url = URI->new('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages');
$url->query_form( access_token => PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN );

my $req = POST($url,
   Content_Type => 'application/json',
   Content      => $message_data,
);
```